# How to resize a logo link inside a header

Tags: html, css

I made a header. It contains only a logo and a website title. The logo is a link to the main page. My problem is that I can't seem to get the logo to be all the way to the left in the header and I want it to resize so it fits into the header (instead of: header gets bigger because of logo). I placed the logo and the website name/title in two different divs.

Setting the with or height to 100% was something that often came by. I have tried to use this, but it wouldn't work. 
"object-fit" should also be an option, but my IDE doesn't recognize this property.
When I use "float: left;" for the logo, it goes all the way to the left, but it also goes out of the header (well, it looks like it does) and pushes my other divs beneath the header/page content to the right.

the HTML:

```
        <div class="header">
            <a href="index.html" class="logo">
                <img src="image.png">
            </a>
            <div class="header-right">
                <h1>Website title/name</h1>     
            </div>
        </div>
```

the CSS:

```
.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one way you can achieve this by having two images one for desktop version and other for mobile version.  Using window.navigator you can identify whether you are in mobile or in desktop.

Sometimes resizing the logo may shrink and may not look good. Instead having two different logos (small one for mobile = small size) should serve your purpose.

Comment: I only need a desktop version of this website. The problem is not just for the mobile version. I want the logo to automatically resize -> smaller, so it fits in the header. (my bad, I used the word "responsive".)

Comment: So, i am assuming that you came across this scenario while trying to resize the window of your browser. 

HTML:

<div class="header">
            <a href="index.html" class="logo">
                <img  width="250px" height=" 120px" src="image.png">
            </a>
            <div class="header-right">
                <h1>Website title/name</h1>     
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: CSS:

@media (max-width: 480px) { 

.logo{
  display: block;
width: 120px;
  margin-left: auto;


}
} 

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

Comment: hmm, this only makes the image smaller. It is still above the title.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

<style>

.header { 
background-color: #f1f1f1; 
padding: 20px; 
text-align: center; 
} 
.logo{ 
float: left;
display: block; 
margin-left: auto; 
width:250px;
height: 50px;
height: auto; 
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">

            <a href="index.html" class="logo">
                <img width="200px" height="150px"  src="https://groceriesandveggies.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/gv_small_logo.jpeg">
            </a> 
            <div class="header-right">
                <h1>Website title/name</h1>     
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```